# The ubuntu kernel (Vmware) does not have in the /usr/include/linux/fs.h file the struct file_operations structure

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-16.04

Following the tutorial:

http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/

After execute in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36
```

Why the ubuntu kernel (Vmware) does not have in the /usr/include/linux/fs.h file the file_operations  structure?

```
struct file_operations {
       struct module *owner;
       loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
       ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
       ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
    .
    .   
    .
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

These headers are for userspace programs. Why would you expect the in-kernel fs.h file to be in there? What are you doing in the first place?

If you check the kernel source tree you will see it contains a separate set of headers at usr/include/linux.

Possible package you are looking for is named -devel (or -dev). apt-file search should be able to tell you, or preferably manual for whatever you are supposed to be doing here.

EDIT:

The author of the tutorial means include/linux/fs.h file in the kernel source tree.

The tutorial is of extremely poor quality and must not be followed. Further, it seems you yourself are a beginner programmer in general and in this case I strongly discourage playing with the kernel at this stage.

Comment: Thank you Employee I edited the question with the link of the tutorial that i am  trying to follow.